# Clustering algorithm for mixed data with non constant categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, mixed-type-data

I have the following scenario, imagine that I have a dataset as follows:

```
product     quantity   price
C            1           $3
Coke         2           $2.99
Chips        2           $2.50
chips        1           $3
c            1           $2.5
```

in which the first product (one C with price tag of $3) it's a coca cola, the second one also is a coca cola, and the last 3 rows are chips. I would like to use a cluster algorithm that could efficiently cluster them by taking into account their price, quantity and product description, however due to the fact that the product column might be highly variable (ex. a shop might label coca-cola as 'c' but another shop might label it as 'C' or 'coke' or even another shop might label chips as 'c') I was wondering if there might be a way to correctly cluster each element into a cluster with elements that are very similar between each other. At first I wanted to apply k-medioids but I believe it will not be suitable since the product variable is highly variable. If anybody knows an algorithm that I could apply or any other recommendation/insight I will appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect this is going to be very difficult unless you can say something more specific about the structure of the product descriptions.

Comment: Hi @user20160, sorry I didn't get what you mean. About product descriptions I meant the product column in the example that I gave, which in this case is a character string but that's it. In theory I could also get detailed info for each product (ex. for Coke i could get Coca cola 500 ml but it is still pending to see if that is possible)

Comment: This is not a clustering question. This is the question about what to do with qualitative, open ended, highly dirty data. If you want variable "product" to participate along with others in cluster analysis you should first make its data crisp.

Comment: @Oliver What I mean is that if you only know that the product description is an arbitrary string, it can't be used to help identify similar products. Some additional knowledge of how strings relate to each other and/or product identity would be required. Alternatively, it may be possible to learn this from data if a suitably large dataset is available with different descriptions of products that are known to be the same.

Comment: @ttnphns, unfortunately most of the data is not dirty, only the product column is the one that varies. What I want to do is try to get as many elements as possible, and match them with their respective counterpart in another 'cleaner dataset'. That is why I would like to do some kind of clustering, even if I can recover at least 10% of the elements.

Comment: @user20160, ok, I understand what you mean. In this case maybe the quantity and/or price might help to relate different products' names. However which method would you recommend me to do this?